# Is there anyway, to load/visit a full webpage (all the subpages) using a bot?

Tags: caching, web-crawler, bots

Currently I have a webpage, which works with varnish caching. However for this cache to work, the page must be visited before it starts loading from cache. My problem is that I have thousand of pages in this site, and I cant visit them one by one, because it would take a lot. Is there any webcrawler or something similar to do this task? Just to visit the page, because visiting the page generates the cache file, and then it works way faster.

Answer (score 0):

just generate a sitemap with an online sitemap generator, it will crawl all the site